# can't copy files from appdata folder

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to copy some DLLs from the `APPDATA` to the system root and register them,
but I keep getting "path not found error".

```
On Error Resume Next
Const OverwriteExisting = True
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFile "%AppData%\something\something\something\x64\*.dll" , "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\" , OverwriteExisting
objFSO.CopyFile "%AppData%\something\something\something\x86\*.dll" , "C:\Windows\System32\" , OverwriteExisting

Dim objShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.run "c:\windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe /s c:\windows\SysWOW64\something.dll" 
WshShell.run "c:\windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe /s c:\windows\SysWOW64\something.dll" 
WshShell.run "c:\windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe /s c:\windows\SysWOW64\something.dll" 
wscript.sleep 1000
WshShell.run "c:\windows\System32\regsvr32.exe /s c:\windows\SysWOW64\something.dll" 
WshShell.run "c:\windows\System32\regsvr32.exe /s c:\windows\SysWOW64\something.dll" 
WshShell.run "c:\windows\System32\regsvr32.exe /s c:\windows\SysWOW64\something.dll"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileSystemObject` methods don't expand environment variables. Change this:

```
objFSO.CopyFile "%AppData%\something\something\something\x64\*.dll" , "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\" , OverwriteExisting
objFSO.CopyFile "%AppData%\something\something\something\x86\*.dll" , "C:\Windows\System32\" , OverwriteExisting
```

into this:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
appdata = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
src = objFSO.BuildPath(appdata, "something\something\something\x64\*.dll")
objFSO.CopyFile src, "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\", OverwriteExisting
src = objFSO.BuildPath(appdata, "something\something\something\x86\*.dll")
objFSO.CopyFile src, "C:\Windows\system32\", OverwriteExisting
```

However, your logic is wrong here. Despite the (misleading) names the `system32` folder contains the 64-bit files and the `SysWOW64` folder contains 32-bit files on 64-bit systems, so you need to switch destination folders:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
appdata = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
src = objFSO.BuildPath(appdata, "something\something\something\x64\*.dll")
objFSO.CopyFile src, "C:\Windows\system32\", OverwriteExisting
src = objFSO.BuildPath(appdata, "something\something\something\x86\*.dll")
objFSO.CopyFile src, "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\", OverwriteExisting
```

If you have 32-bit systems as well, you need to detect the OS architecture and copy the files depending on the results of that test:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
appdata = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
If sh.Environment("PROCESS")("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE") = "AMD64" Then
  src = objFSO.BuildPath(appdata, "something\something\something\x64\*.dll")
  objFSO.CopyFile src, "C:\Windows\system32\", OverwriteExisting
  src = objFSO.BuildPath(appdata, "something\something\something\x86\*.dll")
  objFSO.CopyFile src, "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\", OverwriteExisting
Else
  src = objFSO.BuildPath(appdata, "something\something\something\x86\*.dll")
  objFSO.CopyFile src, "C:\Windows\system32\", OverwriteExisting
End If
```